Algorithm to find polygons given a set of lines and points
I am trying to automate my workflow in GeoStudio. It involves getting a section from AutoCAD and plotting it into GeoStudio. So far, I am extracting information about the points and lines from the CAD file.
My problem is that I need to identify the points that create regions so that I can input these points into GeoStudio. It wasn’t a big problem for regions that have a rectangular shape, but the other polygons do not have a specific set of rules (at least not that I know of) to identify the points that create them.
How can I go about doing this? I guess it would be better to use an algorithm, but any solution that works is much appreciated! I have added two files with some examples of the sections we might encounter, so you can have an idea of how the sections are made.


I have already tried using DFS and BFS algorithms, but with no luck. Additionally, the triangulation algorithm is not suitable for me, as it divides my section into much smaller pieces, creating more work instead of minimizing it.

Use NetworkX to find "regions".

Adding to @user24714692 's comment: assuming I understand your question correctly, and assuming all "regions" are convex, then a "region" is a chordless cycle, so you can use networkx.algorithms.cycles.chordless_cycles. If regions can have concavities though, then they can also have outside chords, so non-convex regions might be missed by this.
